# MySQL on XAMPP shutdown unexpectedly every time I activate it

Tags: mysql, xampp

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
8:33:32 AM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
8:33:32 AM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
8:33:32 AM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
8:33:32 AM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
8:33:32 AM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
8:33:32 AM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

This is from the XAMPP messages itself. It was working before and suddenly I can't seem to run it again.

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-02-08 21:25:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-02-08 21:25:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-02-08 21:25:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-02-08 21:25:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-02-08 21:25:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-02-08 21:25:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-02-08 21:25:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-02-08 21:25:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-02-08 21:25:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-02-08 21:25:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-02-08 21:25:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-02-08 21:25:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-02-08 21:25:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 113872; transaction id 9
2020-02-08 21:25:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-02-08 21:25:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-02-08 21:25:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200208 21:25:02
2020-02-08 21:25:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

These are from mysql_error.log

Comment: Have narrowed down the problem and it seems to be coming from a file called db.MAI file located at XAMPP/mysql/data/mysql/db.MAI. Does anyone know what the file do and why is it causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First try to change the apache port in xampp controller panel

go to config -> Service and port settings -> apache Main port
you can find MySQL tab on the right

Comment: Had tried this, the port is free, nothing was using it and changing the port did not fix it, I think maybe the dependencies are at fault here, maybe

Answer (score 0):

I guess it requires you to change port assigned to mysql service
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-change-the-port-of-a-MySQL-server-in-XAMPP

Comment: I had tried this and it did not fixed the problem, I checked the port and it was not in used by other programs

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to fix , just follow below steps :-

- Open Xampp Control Panel
- Goto Mysql Config
- Open my.ini file (https://prnt.sc/1388sfe)
- Change your port to 3307 in two lines shown on screenshot (https://prnt.sc/1388w0w)
- Save and Restart Xampp.